# IN operator in C

Tags: c, operators

Can I use the "IN" operator in C?

For instance, in searching an array, can I say:

```
if(a in array[i])
{
    printf("%d \n", array[i]);
}
```

In Python, we may say this.

Comment: Well, I'm not intrested in what gana happen in printf... my main concern in in the if condition!

Comment: You can try `strchr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in C syntax that does this. You can write a function that does. Ie, if `array[i]` is an array of `int`s:

```
int in(int n, int* arr, int len) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == n) {
      return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In some contexts such a function might already exist in the standard library. As [n.m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) pointed out, `strchr` finds a pointer to first occurence of a character in a character array, or else `NULL`, so you can do `strchar(array[i], a) == NULL` if `array[i]` is a character array.

Answer (score -1):

No there's no `in` in C language.

If want, you can call a function passing the variable `a` to check if it is there in the array or not, using linear search(or binary depending on the data).

```
if(isKey(a,array))  // if(in(a,array))
{

} 

int isKey(int a, int* array, int size)
{

// code to search element is present return 1 if present else 0
}
```

EDIT :- It was supposed to be a pointer mistake while . and edited for size.

Comment: Not my downvote, but how do you know how big the array is in the function?

Comment: thought just giving a outline of how to solve. and missed a few parameter doing so, my bad.